# How to improve this python vectorial function

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, numpy, vector

I have a function `A` whose input is a numpy vector (numpy.ndarray) called `x`. This function calculates, for each element of `x`, the sum of that element itself with other elements of `x` given by a list of those elements.

The following example should illustrate this better:

```
x = [[2,3], [3,4], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4]] # my input
n = [[1,2,3], [0,4,2], [3,0,1], [0,1,4], [3,1,2]] # list with lists of element to be added for each element in x
```

So for the first element of x, which is x[0] = [2,3] I have to add the values given by n[0], so those are 1, 2 and 3. I obtain them by `x[n[0][0]],x[n[0][1]] and x[n[0][2]]`.

The expected output for the example should be:

```
l = [[11, 18], [13, 21], [9, 16], [9, 20], [8, 21]]
```

The final sum for a element x[i] should be

```
(x[i] + x[n[i][0]] + x[i] + x[n[i][1]] + x[i] + x[n[i][2]])
```

The return of the function is the list with each calculated sum.

As this is iterative I move through both lists x and n. The following code achieve this but goes element by element in both lists x and n.

```
def A(x):
    a = []
    for i, x_i in enumerate(x):
        mysum = np.zeros(2)
        for j, n_j in enumerate(n[i]):
           mysum = mysum + x_i + x[n_j]
        a.append(mysum)
    return np.array(a)
```

I want to make this code more vectorial, but this is my best since some days ago.

Edit: If it is helpful, I always sum 3 values per element, so the sublists of `n` are always of lenght 3.

Comment: How the result came like that? Isn't it `[2,3]+[3,4]+[2,3]+[1,2]+[2,3]+[1,3]=[11,18]` for first element as per your equation of `x[i]`

Comment: It can be done without for loop, but is the answer given in your question right?

Comment: no, the code in the question is my approach

Comment: @AlejandroSazo: Where does `n` come from then? I don't believe the code in your question is either correct or your *actual* implementation. And while we are improving things, how about fixing the title of the question?

Comment: n can be declared before the declaration of the function, so can be implicit used in A(x). Believe what you want, I programmed that code and works, slow but works. Do you need screenshots or something?

Comment: By the way, be more polite next time.

Comment: Your code does not return the result you say you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I did a mental example, not what I was working (a list with 500 items)

Comment: @AbidRahmanK It's true, I'm really sorry for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can at least remove the inner loop as follows:

```
def A(x, n):
    a = 3 * x
    for i in range(len(x)):
        a[i] += np.sum(x[np.ix_(n[i]-1)], axis=0)
    return a
```

Answer (score 5):

*(Please see the **UPDATE** at the end for simpler and faster solution)*

This can be done without the for loop, by the technique of broadcasting

```
def C(x,n):
    y = x[n.ravel()-1]
    z = y.reshape((-1,3,2))
    xx = x[:,np.newaxis,:]
    ans = z+xx
    ans = ans.sum(axis=1)
    return ans
```

It is atleast **5-6x faster** compared to the solution with for loop.

```
In [98]: np.all(A(x,n)==C(x,n))
Out[98]: True

In [95]: %timeit ans=A(x,n)
10000 loops, best of 3: 153 us per loop

In [96]: %timeit ans=C(x,n)
10000 loops, best of 3: 27 us per loop
```

**UPDATE**

**[Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110026/jaime)** has reduced my 6 lines of code into a simple 1-line code (check comments below), and it is 20% faster too.

```
ans = 3*x + x[n-1].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: excellent! I was wondering how costly it would be to work with big arrays of size N * 3 * 2, but I guess I have my answer :)

Comment: Please explain ```x[n.ravel()-1]```.

Comment: `n.ravel()` returns a flattened version of `n`. then apply `-1`. (But I have doubts regarding that, because it doesn't match with the question description. So I modelled my code based on accepted answer). Now, it becomes like `x[[1,2,3,...]]` which will return the row of `x` corresponding to each indices.

Comment: `3*x + x[n-1].sum(axis=1)` does the same as your whole function, and is ~20% faster. And I too do not think the `-1` is needed.

Comment: Cool!!!  please, put it as an answer... It will benefit newcomers... Or I can append this to my answer as an update...

Comment: It is new to me that we can pass any dimension array as indices.